# How do I create a border that fades out

Tags: css, border

Think of a normal border with a solid color for the left, top and right, but I need to have the left and right fade into a blank bottom. Any pointers on how to implement with cross browser support? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with cross browser support, not yet: `border-colors` is part of CSS 3. You would have to use a background image.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be some CSS support for a linear gradient, but oh well.